# Is there a way to join an existing hangout?

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I'm using Google+ API and Google+ Domain API to read user info and events.

Is it possible make a button (or any) to join on in-development hangout?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean a hangout that is already in progress?

Comment: Yes,in an already in progress hangout  @Prisoner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official format for Activities that represent a hangout. You can try searching for them using various hashtags, but these tags have changed (frequently) over time and it is not always easy to get the URL for the hangout.

Depending on your exact scenario, you can get the URL for the hangout that is in progress and share that (possibly via an [Interactive Post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive) or just via a link to the hangout), and this will serve as an invitation.

Getting the URL for the hangout is fairly easy through a Hangout App, although you will need to have one of the people already in the hangout run that app and report it to your server. Take a look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4 for some thoughts about how to write this app.